# Compare numpy array to scalar with 'out=...'

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have an array of strings:

```
s = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and I want to have a function `array_equal_to_scalar` to compare `s` with string `'a'` with writing output to preallocated array (I need fast performance):

```
mask = np.empty(s.shape)
np.array_equal_to_scalar(s, 'a', out=mask)
```

So, I expect `mask` will be

```
> [True False False]
```

Is there any way to make something like `array_equal_to_scalar`?

Comment: What is wrong with `'a' == np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])`? Try `'a' == np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])` and the output should be `array([ True, False, False])`; if you want `mask` to be a `list`, then just convert the result into a list.

Comment: Are you sure allocation is your performance bottleneck?

Comment: @droooze I want to have fast performance, s == np.array['a', 'b', 'c'] will create new array in memory

Comment: I am not convinced that memory saving here would result in performance boost.

Comment: @AndrasDeak absolutely sure, I have to do `np.array_equal_to_scalar(s, value)` 100 000 times with len(s) is about 1 000 000 items.. And numpy will create a new boolean mask in memory every time when I try `value == np.array(['a', 'b', ...])`

Comment: So is the problem the memory consumption, rather than speed? The allocation will take a tiny fraction of the time that the elementwise "==" takes.

Comment: Use `==` and break the comparison up into smaller chunks, then store the result of the chunks in a pre-allocated array/list - unless you want to add functionality to `np.equal` to handle strings.

Comment: @myrtlecat memory allocating of big chunks is a high cost performance operation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`numpy.equal` ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy.equal), which doesn't seem to work for your use case.

In order to use it in the way you want, we need to explicitly broadcast the scalar to be compared into a numpy array of an appropriate shape:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['a','b','c'])
res = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=bool)
np.equal(a, np.broadcast_to(['a'], a.shape), out=res)
```

Unfortunately the above call (1) ignores the broadcast and gives a constant result, and (2) is `NotImplemented`. We can try allocating a proper comparison array to enforce a proper elementwise comparison, to no avail:

```
>>> compare = np.full(a.shape, 'a')
>>> np.equal(a, compare)
NotImplemented
```

It seems that the efficient implementations via numpy `ufunc`s are only given for numeric types (I haven't had time to look into the source yet). But I don't expect higher-level functions to be able to directly work with your pre-allocated input arrays as buffers. With a compiled ufunc I could imagine that the `out` keyword argument lets you bypass the creation of a temporary array, but I don't think there's another alternative for you here.